# Static site form to email eloquent solution?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, email

I have a static site that uses a contact form to get users in touch w me.
When it comes to posting the form data I want it to arrive in my email.

I'm looking for a clean eloquent solution here. I don't want to use any services that cost money such as fromspree and fromkeep.

I've looked into using Nodemailer and Express but since my site is a static site it really doesn't make sense to go set up these tools just for a contact form. I know PHP is the usual way to go about this type of request and [I found this tutorial here](https://sendgrid.com/blog/create-basic-contact-form-sendgrid-php/).

If I where to use this tutorial any ideas on how I would modify it to use 
the [PHP lib that SendGrid developed](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php?__hstc=111872475.95c52f35fe00ad3f4dc9959aa0185a14.1472422610743.1472424464916.1472428404302.4&__hssc=111872475.1.1472428404302&__hsfp=1353944366) to work with my simple form?

There is another approach to dealing with static site contact forms via hacking google forms [through google apps script](https://github.com/dwyl/html-form-send-email-via-google-script-without-server).

Any suggestions here? Or best known methods you for me to use?

Answer (score 2):

You asked for services that do not cost money and you mention 'sendgrid' so I presume you don't have too many subscribers.

You can use SendGrid by using only client side JavaScript but you will have to put your password\api for anyone to see, that's a bad idea.

For static site I think you can use MailChimp. Just open a free account and you can use their integrated form to submit the forms to yourself.

If you don't want any third party, or SendGrid specifically, you should have to go with server side code. (NodeJS recommended, php also an option)

**Update:** sendgrid no longer provides a free account. You can go for mailjet instead.

**Update:** Today sendgrid support [Signup forms](https://sendgrid.com/solutions/email-marketing/signup-forms/) too